# PHP Date with Timestamp zero returns 1 Hour

Tags: php, date, timezone, timestamp

If I do the following:

```
date("H:i:s", 0);
```

It returns `01:00:00`, while it **should** give `00:00:00`.
Might it have something to do with the Timezone of my localhost? (UTC+1)

If so, how can I fix this?

Comment: Yes, try adjusting the timezone

Comment: yes, it's your timezone. try `date('H:i:s T')` to see what TZ php is filling in.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Set the time zone before calling `date()`. You will use [`date_default_timezone_set()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.date-default-timezone-set.php) for that:

```
date_default_timezone_set('UTC');
echo date("H:i:s", 0);
```

[See it in action](http://codepad.viper-7.com/LGjphx)

Don't forget to set it back if you're doing timezone sensitive operations.

Or:

Here's an alternative way to do it using [`DateTime()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.datetime.php):

```
$dt = new DateTime('@0', new DateTimeZone('UTC'));
echo $dt->format('H:i:s');
```

[See it in action](http://codepad.viper-7.com/q8mAWo)

Comment: Setting the timezone worked for the hours but :echo date('d H:i:s',0); returns : 01 00:00:00

Answer (score 0):

Use `gmdate()` function in place of `date()` function.