# date returning different results in different versions of php

Tags: php

I have a date `A` and `B`.

I wanted to get the hours/minutes between them. Like:

```
date('h:i', strtotime(B) - strtotime(A));
```

But I get strange results:

```
echo date('h:i', strtotime('2014-01-01') - strtotime('2014-01-01'));
// echoes: 01:00 (!)


date_default_timezone_set('Europe/London');
$date = new DateTime();
$A = $date->format('Y-m-d H:i:s'); echo '<br />';
$date->modify("+64 minutes");
$B = $date->format('Y-m-d H:i:s'); echo '<br />';
echo date('h:i', strtotime($B) - strtotime($A));
// echoes 02:04 (!)
```

[**Live example**](http://3v4l.org/467u6) for the previous code:

Why is this and how to get the expected result?

Comment: @MártonMolnár, in my second example I set the timezone, so not dup I think

Comment: @MártonMolnár It's not duplicate. The problem is for versions under 5.0 -> http://3v4l.org/qPZJA

Comment: @MaciejCzyżewski okay, you are right, but there is definitely some problem here with time zones.

Comment: @MártonMolnár check here: http://3v4l.org/467u6

Comment: @Rikard I see only errors for <5.2, but add "T" to the format string to see why the timezone setting is important (like in [the question I linked previously](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16925641/php-date-with-timestamp-zero-returns-1-hour)). Use UTC for correct calculations.

Comment: @MártonMolnár, adding the timezone inside the `DateTime()` gives same problem: http://3v4l.org/QE1MY

Comment: Use `gmdate`, example: http://3v4l.org/QOcpV

Comment: @Rikard $date has timezone info but the difference in date() does not so it uses the default (+1 you set). I'm still not convinced this really isn't a duplicate though... Check the PHP manual: date "takes local date/time", gmdate uses GMT.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is **correct behavior**

Why? Think of it: `strtotime('2014-01-01') - strtotime('2014-01-01')` is **zero** - but `date()` expects *timestamp* as second parameter. So that means, you're trying to get date from zero-point timestamp. And that point is *different* in different timezones. Your `London` TZ has `+01` offset, that's why 0-point timestamp is `01 Jan 1970 01:00:00` - and that's why `date('h:i', 0)` is `01:00`

Try to set, for example, `Moscow` zone:

```
date_default_timezone_set('Europe/Moscow');
$date = new DateTime();
$A = $date->format('Y-m-d H:i:s'); 
$date->modify("+64 minutes");
$B = $date->format('Y-m-d H:i:s'); 

echo date('h:i', strtotime($B) - strtotime($A));//04:04
```

-you'll see exactly 04:04 - because current offset for Moscow is `+03` (so 03 hours + 64 minutes modification)

Comment: Ok, I think I get the point. And btw, __[this](http://3v4l.org/RPbVj)__ is a bug between different versions?

Comment: @Rik That just means the various test systems have different default timezones configured.

Comment: @Rikard The timezone handling was changed in [5.1.0](http://php.net/releases/5_1_0.php).

Answer (score 1):

What `date` expects as its second parameter is an *absolute* timestamp, which it then formats in the specified format. You outputting `h:i` means you're outputting only the *hour:minute* part of a complete *year, month, day, hour, minute, second* timestamp. If you want to format the *relative difference* between two timestamps, `date` is the wrong function to use. The result is expected, since you're actually dealing with *absolute* timestamps in *timezones*.